# ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW while minting an NFT

Tags: transaction, blockfrost, error, mintingpolicy, lucid

I'm currently trying to create a minting process with lucid (v. 0.8.9) using Blockfrost on Mainnet.

Minting policy:

```
const mintingPolicy: MintingPolicy = lucid.utils.nativeScriptFromJson({
    type: "any",
    scripts: [{
        scripts: [{
            keyHash: "ccb1d97578fe819d6df11095a74a96803e5a50460b5cf895aaf40c0d",
            type: "sig"
        }],
        type: "all"
    }, {
        scripts: [{
            keyHash: "66f9337a3873f06478d394058ec7fda75909b359df883b8aaf8ba79d",
            type: "sig"
        }],
        type: "all"
    }, {
        scripts: [{
            keyHash: "6c70c3fc4f73e5bbb54cc87bdf943fad2213da692b260e12749bcc10",
            type: "sig"
        }],
        type: "all"
    }]
});
```

Mint function:

```
export async function mintNFT(name ? : string, ): Promise < TxHash > {
    try {
        const unit: Unit = policyId2;
        const tx = await lucid.newTx().mintAssets({
            [unit]: 1n
        }).attachMintingPolicy(mintingPolicy).validTo(Date.now() + 100_000).complete();
        const signedTx = await tx.sign().complete();
        const txHash = await signedTx.submit();
        console.log(txHash) return txHash;
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.log('Error occured:');
        console.log(e.message);
        return e.message;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash \"f188522db566255b029de7c30e1e5cc14c30ba6649356d9b1ae8ebb5\"]))))])"
```

Where f188522db566255b029de7c30e1e5cc14c30ba6649356d9b1ae8ebb5 is a policyId.

I'm not entirely sure, but the error seems to be fixable by adding invalid-hereafter parameter to a raw transaction in cli OR by signing a transaction with both skey and vkey (I think that currently lucid only signs with vkey), but I didn't find a way to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up the keyHashes in the minting policy and was trying to mint with a different wallet.

[This](https://forum.cardano.org/t/minting-token-with-time-base/59214/13) was extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I have an example that includes both on-chain and off-chain code for minting a multi-sig NFT using Helios.

https://github.com/lley154/helios-examples/tree/main/nft-multisig